# Macbook finder copy changes permissions to 777

Tags: terminal, finder, permission

I recently got my first mac (macbook pro) and I use it primarily for coding C++ and python in the terminal.  I noticed if I use finder to copy a directory (with my code in it) onto a USB drive, then the permissions on all the files get changed to 777.  Is there any way I can use finder to copy files onto a USB and have it preserve the existing permissions?

Answer (score 4):

After some experimentation, I figured out that the USB drive was formatted FAT, and when Finder copies to a disk formatted FAT, the permissions get changed to 777.  When I reformatted the USB drive to MAC OS, then finder copied the files with permissions correctly preserved.

Side Note: Someone suggested the permissions don't really *change* to 777, but rather FAT simply does not support unix permissions.  ***HOWEVER***, I would point out that I first noticed this *not* when I initially copied my files to the usb drive, but when I copied them *back to my macbook* from the usb drive, and then I saw that ***on my macbook the permissions were now 777***.  So, in effect, FAT's non-support of unix permissions actually ***did*** change the permissions to 777.